# Ansible can't find roles from collection

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-collections

I got collection that has structure

```
   namespace/
── collectionA/
   ├── docs/
   ├── galaxy.yml
   ├── README.md
   └── roles/
        ├── roleA/
        |     └── tasks/
        |           ├──taskA.yml
        |           ├──taskB.yml
        └── roleB/
               └── tasks/
                    ├──taskA.yml
                    ├──taskB.yml
```

according to [using collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/collections_using.html#using-collections-in-a-playbook) if I wan to use that roles all I have to do is include_role with fqdn

```
- hosts: all
  collections:
    - my_namespace.my_collection

tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: role1
```

but it seems not working. I still get error:

> ERROR! the role 'manage_users' was not found in edaas.post_provisioning:ansible.legacy:/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Create_Infra/playbooks/roles:/home/cirunner/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Create_Infra/playbooks
> 12:10:53
> 12:10:53  The error appears to be in '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Create_Infra/playbooks/ansible_main_initial.yml': line 24, column 15, but may
> 12:10:53  be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
> 12:10:53
> 12:10:53  The offending line appears to be:
> 12:10:53
> 12:10:53      - ansible.builtin.import_role:
> 12:10:53          name: manage_users
> 12:10:53                ^ here

Collection is installed correctly - checked by ansible-galaxy collection list

Any idea what can be still wrong? Role names are aligned to rules (lowercase and only characters with _
Collection is installed in /home/cirunner/.ansible/collections

> ansible [core 2.11.12]    config file = None   configured module
> search path = ['/home/cirunner/.ansible/plugins/modules',
> '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']   ansible python module location
> = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible   ansible collection location = /home/cirunner/.ansible/collections   executable location =
> /usr/local/bin/ansible   python version = 3.8.0 (default, Dec  9 2021,
> 17:53:27) [GCC 8.4.0]   jinja version = 3.1.2   libyaml = True

Comment: Run an `ansible --version` on your Jenkins box and confirm that the path `/home/cirunner/.ansible/collections`  is listed under `ansible collection location`

Comment: It's correct
 
`ansible [core 2.11.12] 
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/cirunner/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/cirunner/.ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.0 (default, Dec  9 2021, 17:53:27) [GCC 8.4.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True`

Comment: Please don't add this kind of information needed to answer your question and consisting of large pieces of output in a comment: [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72814254/edit).

Comment: Please make sure the exact path to your collection is `/home/cirunner/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/my_namespace/my_collection`. The `ansible_collections` inside the path is mandatory as a sub-directory of the configured search path.

Comment: IT's installed correctly
`# /home/cirunner/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection              Version
----------------------- -------
namepsace.my_collection 0.0.1`

Comment: Again, please do not add this kind of information in comments. Edit your question with an output of a command equivalent to `tree`, as you did above but with the entire paths and the real names of your folders that match the ones you pasted in your error message. On a more general level please see [How to create a minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry I can't publish real structure of files and folders. I guarantee that it's same as in my question, which corresponds to what I've found in official documentation. If you think that it's not enough then specify which information you need, I'll try to prepare them, but without original paths and folder names. There is no typos in paths of names.

Comment: if you can't publish your real structure, create your own full minimal and complete example reproducing the problem. This is what is explained in my last link above And regarding your garentee, I totally trust that you **think** everything is installed correctly but I ultimately trust ansible telling you it cannot find your collection/role. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this thread, and my issue was I had hyphens in my role name, which is not supported as per the documentation found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections_structure.html#roles-directory).

Changing to underscores in the role name resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had a similar issue and it took me hours to find my problem. Maybe the way I figured it out will help someone else.

My problem was an empty collection directory left over from some tests in my project directory `<project_dir>/collections/ansible_collection/my_namespace/my_collection` directory. `ansible-galaxy` found the real installed collection containing the role in `/usr/share/ansible/collections` and reported it as installed and everything fine.
But `ansible-playbook` found the empty directory in my project directory first and interpreted this as the collection location and didn't look further to the actual installed collection in `/usr/share/ansible/collections`.

So, how I figured it out and how you might be able to figure out your problem:

1. Explicitly mention the collection in your playbook:

```
...
    collections:
        - my_namespace.my_collection
```

2. Add at least four '-v' arguments when running your playbook:
   `ansible-playbook ... -vvvv`
3. Search for following line and see where your collection was found:
   `Loading collection my_namespace.my_collection from <project_dir>/collections/ansible_collections/my_namespace/my_collection`

I hope it helps.